# Terraform Import creating duplicate configurations

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform

I am trying to import some s3 buckets under terraform state. However, importing an S3 bucket creates conflict for configs that used to be arguments under "aws_s3_bucket" but now have been deprecated and are resources on their own.

The problem is that arguments like: aws_s3_bucket_server_side_encryption_configuration" can mess things up. While I define a "aws_s3_bucket_server_side_encryption_configuration" resource for example to specify the encryption of the bucket, when I do a terraform import on the bucket it appears also as a configuration under the "aws_s3_bucket" resource. That creates a game of cat and mouse where "aws_s3_bucket_server_side_encryption_configuration" creates encryption for S3 -> "aws_s3_bucket" doesn't have S3 encryption in its state -> "aws_s3_bucket" deletes the encryption on the next plan.

Comment: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/guides/version-4-upgrade#s3-bucket-refactor

Comment: Thank you a lot, it didn't occur to me to that the provider was at a previous version! Everything seems to be working properly now.